# Подвисает анимация на Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение в котором используется лоадер. В лоадере есть анимация вращения, а сам лоадер появляется и пропадает используя анимацию свойства Opacity с установкой соответсвующего значения для Visibility.
Пример с лоадером есть на [GitHub](https://github.com/EfimKR/TestAnimation). Само приложение представляет собой вьюшку с панелью навигации и объектом Frame, куда грузятся Page с соответствующим контентом. При первом запросе на отображение, в соотвествующей ViewModel происходит загрузка и приображение данных. В этот момент показывается лоадер. Данные загружаются через async/await методы, используется .net 4.7.2.

Проблема заключается в следующем: на некоторых машинах с Windows 10 анимация вращения лоадера и анимация Opacity происходит рывками (как будто UI поток обрабатывает длительную задачу), UI при этом остается отзывчивым (можно перейти на другую вкладку, изменить размер окна и прочее). На машинах с Windows 7 таких проблем не замечено, часть машин с Windows 10 также отрабатывают анимацию корректно.

Пробовал запускать тестовый проект (ссылка выше) на машинах, где есть проблема с анимацией - в тестовом проекте проблем нет. Т.е. можно предположить, что в приложении что-то грузит UI поток. Как это можно отладить и исправить?

Путем исключения установил, что приводит к подвисанию анимации. Приложение сделано адаптивным под разную ширину окна. Сделано это сменой ContentTemplate. Буду думать как это исправить.

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
             <ContentControl.Style>
                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                     <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource fourColumnsTemplate}" />
                     <Style.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Converter={local:AllFundsItemTemplateSelectorConverter}}"
                                                 Value="oneColumn">
                             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource oneColumnTemplate}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>

                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Converter={local:AllFundsItemTemplateSelectorConverter}}"
                                                 Value="twoColumns">
                             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource twoColumnsTemplate}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                         </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>
                 </ContentControl.Style>
             </ContentControl>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

UPDATE!!! В общем проблема в другом: при загрузке страницы UI поток полностью загружен компоновкой, в итоге анимация лоадера ждет, когда UI осовободится. Будет решено изменением процесса загрузки.

Comment: Могу только профилирование процессора и памяти, подвисания может вызывать даже Garbage Collector, если у вас много мусора и недостаточно памяти. Профилируйте, смотрите, что у вас там тяжелое выполняется, и как работает GC. Объективно ответить на ваш вопрос, к сожалению, не могу.

Comment: @aepot, тоже думаю в этом направлении. Предлагаю, что это код самого фреймворка выполняется по другому, чем на Win7, что может привести к загруженности UI потока. Если не найду как это решить - буду ждать обновления Win10.

Comment: Посмотрел ваш пример. Там в принципе лагать нечему. Кстати, пробовали фреймрейт анимации поднимать, скажем, до 60? Влияет ли это на частоту появления лагов и их длительность? Выглядит намного приятнее, потому что 24 кадра, это как бы для кино нормально, а не для анимации. :) Минимум 30 рекомендую, а еще лучше - оставить дефолтный и вообще не указывать. Воспроизвести рывки на тестовом не смог (Win10). Так что скорее всего у вас где-то в коде нагрузка на UI поток идет, не связанном с анимациями и отрисовками.

Comment: @aepot, да подвисание анимации очень странное, и не всегда воспроизводится. Еще заметил, что также подвисает анимация смены Background, Foreground и FontWeight при переключении кнопок в навигационной панели. Тестовый пример на машинах, где подвисает анимация в рабочем приложении также отрабатывает нормально. Думаю на await/async, буду смотреть в понедельник. Если бы что-то вешало UI поток, то на Win7 также должно наблюдаться подвисание анимации, но там все нормально, как и на некоторых машинах с Win10. Фреймрейт я ставил пытаясь побороть подвисание, но это не помогло. А так там было дефолтное.

Comment: `async` - это машина состояний, она хоть и дает оверхед, но настолько минимальный, что 1000 вызовов в секунду вряд-ли что-то зафризили. `await` - это асинхронное ожидание, и если он вызван даже из UI потока, он как раз и делает то, что освобождает этот поток. С другой стороны анимация - штука не дешевая, и если их много, и их сопровождает огромное количество триггеров - это может сказаться на производительности интерфейса, так что все хорошо, что в меру. Но ответ может дать только профилирование, желательно на проблемной машине.

Comment: @aepot, про async/await знаю, но странный баг приводит к странным предположениям. Буду профилировать. Коллега смотрел на домашней машине с Win 10, при запуске с использованием дискретной видеокарты приложение работает нормально, при запуске на интегрированой - подвисает. RenderMode.SoftwareOnly используется.

Comment: @aepot, нашел, что вызывает подвисание, добавил в описание вопроса.

Comment: очевидно же, что не темплейт надо менять, а стиль. :)

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758592/changing-style-from-inside-a-datatrigger) один из вариантов, как сделать смену стиля через триггер. Смена темплейта вызывает уничтожение и пересоздание всех контролов, поэтому вешать такое на триггер - специфическое решение.

Comment: @aepot, возможно. До недавнего времени не было проблем с этим.

Comment: Я слышал про какие-то квоты на отрисовку интерфейса, типа если операция отрисовки не проходит в отведенное время, то она выбрасывается в очередь и дорисуется в другой итерации рендера. Но конкретно как это работает - я не знаю. Могу наврать. Может кто другой здесь подскажет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109381/discussion-between---and-aepot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема анимации в том, что UI поток занят созданием контролов для отображения загруженных данных. Была идея раздробить одну большую задачу создания контролов на несколько мелких, но данный подход не сработал и код при этом стал сложный для понимания.
Решение может быть получено, если создать отдельный UI поток для отображения лоадера.
Как это сделать описано [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dwayneneed/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual) и [тут](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2014/12/03/wpf-round-table-part-2-multi-ui-threaded-control/).